# RxJS custom operator generic type guarding

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'd like to create a custom `distinctUntilChanged` operator, that compares dates. I'm using `date-fns/isEqual` helper function, hovever I can't find out the proper types.
I'd like to have an error when using the operator with a `string | Date | number | null | undefined` stream as the operator should not handle other types than `Date | number | null | undefined`. If I remove the `Date` or `number` from the `Subject`'s type it shows `Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible` but the extra `string` does not bother it.

```js
import { isEqual } from 'date-fns';
import { distinctUntilChanged, MonoTypeOperatorFunction, Subject } from 'rxjs';

export function distinctUntilDifferentDay<
  T extends Date | number
>(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T | undefined | null> {
  return (source) =>
    source.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged((previous, current) => {
        if (previous === current) {
          return true;
        }
        if (previous != null && current != null) {
          return isEqual(previous, current);
        }
        return false;
      })
    );
}


const s = new Subject<string | number | Date | null | undefined>();
/** There should be a compile error as the subject can emit string */
s.pipe(distinctUntilDifferentDay()).subscribe((a) => console.log(a));

s.next(null);
s.next('apple');
s.next('pear');
```

[Custom RxJS operator Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-9qxpdk)

My tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I get a TS compiler error when I copy and paste this into vscode.

Comment: It works as expected I don't get your question.

Comment: What is the actual question? If you don't want a type, exclude it? I don't get the error you are supposedly getting, maybe it's an issue in your local environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DanielB said in comments it was my local and Stackblitz environment. I was doing it right, but I had to enable the [strictFunctionTypes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes) in my `tsconfig.json`

After adding

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    ...
},
```

to my `tsconfig.json` the compiler raises the error.